# Form Not getting Closed Completely while using "this.Close()"

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio-2010

**I'm Using Visual Studio 2010 And I'm troubling with a problem in my project right now . this question you may feel like foolishness . But i don't know what happening.**

In my Project there are 3 forms .

- Form1
- Form2
- DisplayFrm

I was trying to Open a form(DisplayFrm) using two Other forms(Form1 and Form2)

> **This is the code That i used to open the "DisplayFrm" using Both "Form1" and "Form2"**

```
        DisplayFrm.InitialLoadCustProf = RegCustIDtextBox.Text;
        DisplayFrm frm = new DisplayFrm();
        frm.ShowDialog();
```

- I have Opened **"DisplayFrm"** Using **From1**
- After Doing some Operations Over there I have Closed that Form using **[X] button in Title bar**.
- (Also i have tried by giving **this.Close();** in a separate button)

The problem is that ,when i am opening **DisplayFrm** agian using **Form2** ,it's not starting as a fresh form . it simply restoring the **DisplayFrm** which i have already Closed Before with the Operations i have done Already.

- I don't have this trouble with any other project . I think my project crashed ..it does not showing any kind of error.
- is there any way to use this.dispose(); with form Closing event?.Currently that not working Fine .
- Why my Form is not Getting Closed ? . Why it is behaving like i have used **this.hide();** and **this.show();** ?

Comment: Do you use some kind of static variables inside the DisplayForm class? Are these variables (if any) involved in keeping the state of work done in the DisplayForm? And finally are you creating a _new DisplayForm()_ inside the form2 code?

Answer (score 1):

`DisplayFrm.InitialLoadCustProf` seems to be static. Try to change it to an instance property and open the form like this:

```
using( DisplayFrm frm = new DisplayFrm() )
{
    frm.InitialLoadCustProf = RegCustIDtextBox.Text;
    frm.ShowDialog( this );
}
```